# How would you finish this basement window?

Tags: basement, windows

I have what I think to be two easy questions to answer (hopefully). I am in the middle of replacing some single-pane basement windows with a newer style. This is my first time doing this and I've only done 1 of 6 so far.

1. Should I have installed flashing around this window? I am working with limited space and the window is under a 3-4" edge of the where the housing starts. I'm thinking that it shouldn't be too exposed to the weather.
2. I have screwed and spray foamed (low expansion) around the window and it is now secure, but I'm not sure how to finish the exterior as seen below. Would you add some sort of weather-proof trim or use some kind of black caulking to seal the foam?

Thanks!

[image: window1]

[image: window2]

Comment: Grass, some gravel or a patio tile on the ground just outside the window will reduce the amount of mud that splashes onto the window when it rains or when you hose it down.

Comment: I think I'd be tempted to just use some paintable caulk to cover the foam (assuming it's relatively flush) and paint over it.  If you don't cover the foam it'll degrade over time from the sunlight.  Make sure to leave the drain holes free.